# Use android AudioRecord to get 32 bit samples?

Tags: android, audio-recording, 32-bit

I've been doing a big research and could not find lots of info about this. I want to record audio samples using android AudioRecorder but I don't know how to do it in 32 bit format. Im using also AudioTrack to "monitor" the mic and listen to the audio while recording but if I set AudioManager and AudioTrack to `ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT` the audio literally is null, I can't listen anything.

So the question is how to record and listen at the same time with `AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT` in 32 bit samples so I can get the best quality audio.

This is a quick look of how Im initializing AudioRecord using [AXET Audio Library](https://gitlab.com/axet/android-audio-library):

```
final AudioRecord recorder = Sound.createAudioRecorder(context, sampleRate, ss, 0);

AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);


final int maxJitter = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);


audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION,sampleRate,AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT,maxJitter, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);   
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
```

Inside the Thread I just write the buffer to the audioTrack:

```
audioTrack.write(buffer,0,bufferSize);
```

My buffer is a short[] array.

Finally I run thread and play the track, as I told in PCM_16BIT works great, but in PCM_FLOAT doesn't:

```
thread.start();
audioTrack.play();
```

So if anybody has experience recording in 32 bit I would be appreciated in knowing how it's done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you change short array to float when using ENCODING_PCM_FLOAT? When using 32-bit encoding there is also a different method for reading data from AudioRecord:

```
read(float[] audioData, int offsetInFloats, int sizeInFloats, int readMode)
```